# Find div using dynamic value in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find div using dynamic value.
If I provide id directly, it works well. but if I assigned it to variable and use it means, it wont work.

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const selectedOrderId = urlParams.get('OrderId'); //102251
    var name = "#collapse" + selectedOrderId.toString(); 
    console.log($(name));      
    console.log($("#collapse102251"));
```

Above is my code. anyone help me resolve this? this is my output.
[image]

Comment: Because in one of them you search for `collapse102251` and in the other it's `collapse102551`.... `102251<>102551`

Comment: You would have been better off debugging with `console.log(selectedOrderId)`